# How to start cmd without any text under windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am just wondering if it is possable to remeve the text that is already there, I need a blank set or if I can open the command prompt with out any text it you be great

Comment: you can type `cls` to get a clear screen. The only way to make the path text disappear is to make the text black I think.

Comment: cls will indeed clear the screen and only the prompt appears. You can remove the prompt by using the command `prompt`. If you need more, then please explain what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

***Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17405182/2565329) on stack overflow:***

If you want a defined set of commands to run every time you start a command prompt, the best way to achieve that would be to specify an init script in the [AutoRun](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779439.aspx) registry value. Create it like this (an expandable string value allows you to use environment variables like `%USERPROFILE%`):

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun ^
  /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%"USERPROFILE"%\init.cmd" /f
```

Then create a file `init.cmd` in your user's profile folder:

```
@echo off

cls
```

To remove these changes, [delete](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742145.aspx) the registry key:

```
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
```